# Error while deploying cal.com docker image from DockerHub to K8s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy docker image provided by DockerHub for cal.com solution but I am stuck with the deploy process, the migration for some Prisma tables App & App_RoutingForms_Form couldn't be completed.

This is the Github repo for this solution : https://github.com/calcom/docker

```
This is the error message : 
The table public.App does not exist in the current database.
    at zr.handleRequestError (/calcom/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:8308)
    at zr.handleAndLogRequestError (/calcom/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7697)
    at zr.request (/calcom/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7307)
    at async createApp (/calcom/packages/prisma/seed-app-store.ts:169:22)
    at async main (/calcom/packages/prisma/seed-app-store.ts:373:5) {
  code: 'P2021',
  clientVersion: '5.0.0',
  meta: { table: 'public.App' }
}
PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid prisma.app_RoutingForms_Form.findUnique() invocation:

 
The table public.App_RoutingForms_Form does not exist in the current database.
    at zr.handleRequestError (/calcom/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:8308)
    at zr.handleAndLogRequestError (/calcom/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7697)
    at zr.request (/calcom/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7307)
    at async seedAppData (/calcom/packages/prisma/seed-app-store.ts:21:16)
    at async main (/calcom/packages/prisma/seed-app-store.ts:383:3) {
  code: 'P2021',
  clientVersion: '5.0.0',
  meta: { table: 'public.App_RoutingForms_Form' }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea or encountered the same issue ?

Hello, I am trying to deploy docker image provided by DockerHub for cal.com solution but I am stuck with the deploy process, the migration for some Prisma tables App & App_RoutingForms_Form couldn't be completed.

This is the Github repo for this solution : https://github.com/calcom/docker

Does anyone have an idea or encountered the same issue ?

Comment: Local k8s, cloud k8s?

Comment: Also can you add your k8s yaml files?